# New LEDs go dim

Tags: led

Last night, I got this made in China ornamental led chain lights for decking up my balcony. It was working well for a while until about an hour after operation when it became all dim.

I've used such kinds of lights for a few years now (they don't last more than a few months after unwinding) and every time it has rained, the lights kept up. This time is turning out out to be everything but that.

The LEDs are 2 days new from the store.

I suspect the heavy rains during the time they were on.
Or could it be something with the circuitry in the programs PCB? ( I did give in a check for poor soldering but saw that hot glue was used too, contrary to faith on some cold alloy alone ) By programs I mean those one - click - away settings to change the pattern of glow.

I checked the extension box, no probs. The house voltage was alrighty too.

•if it is the water, how may I get these fixed?

•what steps to take to reach a better conclusion at what the problem really is.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Random Chinese-made electrical fixtures are rumored to be flakey, especially in the weather; I doubt it would be worth your money to have them fixed. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Chinese lights that dim sum.  I amuse myself. Your welcome. Are the lights rated to be used outdoors in the rain ?

Comment: Obviously not in the rains, but surely outdoora

Comment: @AnupamDash **NO it is not obvious**. We can not see the packaging that the lights came in, we do not know if they were designed to be used in wet weather.  **WHY** "surely outdoors"?, again we do not know anything about the lights except they are made in China.

Comment: I'm a common man. I've bought a set of common LED ornamentals. From a local store in India. So I am sorry if I wasn't clear beforehand. But shouldn't a good deal of tape on each bulb be enough of resistance to seepage?

Comment: @AnupamDash Understood, but we can not answer your questions if we do not have all the information about the lights. No, A good deal of tape is not enough if the tape is not made for wet weather. Wet weather lights would not be made with tape, they would have sealed components.

Comment: Okay. After this site's tour, I understand that.

Comment: Yeah, tape is pretty unreliable for seepage.  This has been a vexation for people making automotive splices for many years.  The latest tech is a gooey shrinkwrap that has an inner gelatin glue that goes liquid when you heat itl.  It's a HARD problem.   Also Chinese junk is junk, and a significant failure rate is normal, you are *expected* to take the defective item back to the store, and the store doesn't care because they charged $10 for a thing that cost them $1.

Comment: I agree with Harper, almost all LED lights are made overseas. I only purchase lights that are dlc listed they have a 5 year warranty, some of the earlier led lamps I purchased were horrible, it was not the LED’s but the drivers or bad solder joints. Out of maybe 30 failures all but 1 could be repaired but the cost of the drivers was more than a new light, the others I was able to fix the cold solder joints. Is it worth the time to fix them? On the big ones yes, but the fluorescent replacements no.